# Data exchange from old to new iphone

Tags: iphone, backup, exchange, data

How to transfer apps and its data from one iphone to another through hard disk? Since I am changing my laptop. 
I want to know whether the backup includes app data also? What i mean is when i restore the new phone with the backup, all the apps would get restored on it even if it is another laptop not the one in which the old iphone backup was taken?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the location of the iPhone backup and it's easy to restore your new iPhone from the backup. Here are the locations for different operating systems:

```
Mac: (user)/library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/
Windows Vista/7: \Users\(user name)\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\
Windows XP: \Documents and Settings\(user name)\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\
```